# Add/Remove Class Using Jquery (In View Or Code Behind)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net webfore application which on the page i have an accordion and in that it has some fields. On the first asp:textbox it has an `onclick` as it checks my db to see if the user exists or not. If they do an asp:Label is then displayed.

The issue i have is that when ever i click outside or tab out this field my accordion closes and i need it to stay open. I was think though is is possible to do this via JQuery even though my field has the `onclick` or do i need to add it to my code behind?

In my view i tried

```
$("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function ()
{
    if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '')
    {
        $('panel-collapse collapse').removeClass('collapse');
        $(this).addClass('in');
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work

In my code behind i tried

```
#region Checks if user exists in 'Users' db when field clicked out of
protected void txtRemoveUser_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRemoveUser.Text))
    {
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Name = @Name", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtRemoveUser.Text);
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            removeUserNotExist.Visible = false;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>function endRequestHandler(sender, args){$('#collapseOne').collapse.in()};</script>", false);
        }
        else
        {
            removeUserNotExist.Visible = true;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>function endRequestHandler(sender, args){$('#collapseOne').collapse.in()};</script>", false);
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

but this too doesn't work

The HTML of my accordion is

```
<div id="RemoveUser" class="panel-group"> 
    <div class="panel panel-default"> 
        <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <h3 class="panel-title"> 
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="accordion-toggle collapsed">Remove Users From The List</a> 
            </h3> 
        </div> 
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>If you would like to remove yourself or someone else from the list, please populate all the fields below ensuring to enter the <b>FULL</b> name of the user (whether its you or another user) and then click the 'Remove From List' button.</p>                    
                <asp:Label ID="removeUserNotExist" runat="server" Text="The user entered does not exist. Please try again." Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>
                <div class="form-group">        
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Enter Name To Be Removed</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtRemoveUser_TextChanged" />
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0px">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRemoveUser" Text="Remove From List" CssClass="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeUserModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" ToolTip="Click to remove the specified user from the payday lunch list." />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

None of these appear to work. I may be completly wrong in what i have done though.

Comment: Clarifying which Javascript libraries you are using would increase your chance of getting a good answer. What is `collapse.in()`? As an aside, I think most of your pain would be resolved by switching to AJAX instead of an autopostback.

Comment: When you tab out it causes a postback, and so the state of the accordion is lost. You can use a hidden field to maintain the state of accordion and on page load (document.ready function) reopen the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the `accordion` is getting lost on postback (which gets triggered on the textbox's text change event). One way to handle this is to maintain the value in a hidden field and then use this value to reset the `accordion`.

In `.aspx` add

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SetAccVisible" />
```

Then the corresponding javascript changes to:

```
    $('document').ready(function () {
        var hdnFldId = '<%= SetAccVisible.ClientID %>';
        $("#txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function () {
            //Set value of hidden field to show panel after postback
            $('#' + hdnFldId).val(true);
        });


        if ($('#' + hdnFldId).val() == 'true') {
            showPanel();
            //lets reset the value
            $('#' + hdnFldId).val(false);
        }

        function showPanel() {
            if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '') {
                $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('collapse').addClass('in');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dont suppose you know the answer for to keep a modal open do you? Its the same scenario but in a modal instead. so field checks db once tabbed out of. I have a post for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651026/stop-modal-closing-when-ontextchanged-fires

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class selector to target element. It should be:

```
$('.panel-collapse.collapse').removeClass('collapse');
```

Comment: It still closes when i tab out the field

Answer (score 0):

In your Jquery, you have a little problem with your selector :

```
$("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function ()
{
    if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '')
    {
        $('.panel-collapse .collapse').removeClass('collapse');
        $(this).addClass('in');
    }
});
```

You forget the point before the class selector ;) 
You can read more about JQuery selector here => 
https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Also, you can optimize your Jquery code :

```
$("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function ()
{
    if ($(this).val()) // == if $(#MainContent_txtRemoveUser).val() != ""
    {
        $('.panel-collapse .collapse').removeClass('collapse');
        $(this).addClass('in');
    }
});
```

You check the value of the selector's function (#MainContent_txtRemoveUser")

You can use the '$(this)' selector for call it again, in the function. ^^

And, don't forgot you can use a breakpoint in your browser for check your javascript!

Hope I help you :p

Comment: It still closes when i tab out the field

Comment: the "collapse" attribute isn't removed? or the "in" class is not added? or both of them?

Comment: When the page loads the panel is 'collapse' then i expand it by clicking on it. then when i type in my field and press the 'tab' key, the accordion closes again. I dont know if this is because once you tab or click out of the field it dropd into my code behind to check the name entered exists, if it doesn't my hidden label is displayed. would it be better to try and add this in the code behind then? and if so do you know how?

Comment: Okay, I don't find your "#MainContent_txtRemoveUser" element in your HTML,.. Do you not just call the "#txtRemoveUser' element? 
When you place a breakpoint in your javascript function,  val() is empty?

Comment: As its an asp.net app it add 'MainContent_' to the start of all my asp: id's if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '') comes back as 'true' when i type in the field

Comment: Okay! Thanks for explain (I don't use ASP ^^) And, in the function, did the "collapse" class was removed ?